# Equivalent of Win32 function ::FlushFileBuffers on Android

Tags: android-ndk

I have a simple write-ahead logging implementation in C++ on Win32 platform that write changes to a log file then does

```
::FlushFileBuffers(m_hLogFile);
```

then write the changes to the data file, does

```
::FlushFileBuffers(m_hDataFile);
```

and then clears the log with

```
::SetFilePointerEx(m_hLogFile, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
::SetEndOfFile(m_hLogFile);
```

What are the equivalent functions on Android (saying more exactly, in Android NDK)?

Comment: If you work with FILE set of functions: fopen, fwrite, fprintf… then there is fflush() for you.

Comment: @AlexCohn but there is ftruncate()